# Intersection of affine varieties with curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $p(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})$ be a polynomial, and $V(p)$ its "real" affine variety, 
$$
V(p):=\{(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: p(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})=0\}
$$

For a better exposition, we will assume that $W:=V(p)\cap [0,1]^{n}\neq \emptyset$. Also, let $g_{\alpha}:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]^{n}$ a family of continuous functions, with $\alpha\in(0,1)$, obeying the following properties:

(1) Fixed $\alpha$, for every point $P\in[0,1]^{n}$ there is $t\in [0,1]$ with $\|P-g(t)\|\leq \alpha$ (here, $\|\cdot\|$ means the Euclidean norm).

(2) Putting $g_{\alpha}:=(g^{(1)}_{\alpha},\ldots, g^{(n)}_{\alpha})$, $g^{(i)}_{\alpha}([0,1])=[0,1]$ for each $i=1,\ldots, n$.

What conditions have to satisfies  $W$ to ensure  that $W\cap g_{\alpha}(I)\neq \emptyset$ for enough small $\alpha$?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in \Bbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, it is a UFD so it makes sense to factorize $f$ and assume it is irreducible, then $(f)$ is a prime ideal.

Assume $f$ depends on $x_n$. For $u\in \Bbb{C}^{n-1},v\in \Bbb{C}$ let $F_u(t)=f(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1},t)\in \Bbb{C}[t]$ and $\Delta(u,v)= Disc(F_u)$ (the discriminant), $V(f)=\{ (u,v)\in \Bbb{C}^{n-1}\times \Bbb{C},f(u,v)=0\}$.

$V(\Delta)\cap V(f)=V(f,\Delta)$. Because $(f)$ is a prime ideal then $V(f)$ is an union of finitely many complex irreducible hypersurfaces and $\Delta\not \in (f)$ so that $V(\Delta)\cap V(f)$ is of codimension $2$.

> If $V(f)\cap \Bbb{R}^n$ contains an hypersurface $H$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ then take any point $(u,v)\in H,\not \in V(\Delta)$, that $\Delta(u,v)\ne 0$ means $v$ is a simple root of $F_u(t)$, thus we know that for every $u'\in \Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ close to $u$, $F_{u'}(t)$ has only one root $\rho(u')$ close to $v$, and  since the complex roots come by pair, it must be a real root. Whence the map $u'\to (u',\rho(u'))$ is a local parametrization of $H$.

Note that we can prove the existence of $(u,v)$ just from a sign change, no need to find its exact expression.

Locally $H$ looks like an hyperplane with its left and right side, and your continuous function $g_\alpha$ goes from one side to the other thus it has to cross $H$.

A case with no such hypersurface : $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, having only one real zero. When restricting to $[0,1]^n$ you need to find a real point $(u,v)\in V(f)\cap (0,1)^n$, this is to avoid a case like $f(x,y)=x$ whose vanishing set is contained in the boundary of $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: Dear renus, many thanks for your precise answer. I do not see clear at all two details: (1) What means $V(f,\Delta)$? (2) Whats means "Locally H looks like a hyperplane"?

Comment: $V(\Delta)\cap V(f)=V(f,\Delta)$ the common zeros of $f,\Delta$. Locally the hypersurface looks like an hyperplane.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.